# spring boot not setting csrf cookie in browser

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot

```
// .cors() uses by default uses a Bean by the name of corsConfigurationSource
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    //get origin from application properties
    List<String> allowOrigins = Arrays.asList(origin);
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(allowOrigins);
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("*"));
    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
    //in case authentication is enabled this flag MUST be set, otherwise CORS requests will fail
    configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}
private CookieCsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
    CookieCsrfTokenRepository repository = CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse();
    repository.setSecure(false);
    return repository;
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    //hasAuthority(‘ROLE_ADMIN') is similar to hasRole(‘ADMIN')
    //because the ‘ROLE_‘ prefix gets added automatically.

    //hasRole(myString)  ads "ROLE_" to string and checks that way.
    //for instance if in database we have "ROLE_ADMIN" and we provide hasRole("ADMIN") it will work.

    // .cors() uses by default uses a Bean by the name of corsConfigurationSource
    http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .cors().configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource())
            .and()
            .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository())
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/utility/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/security/auth/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/security/getCsrfToken").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/security/user/getUser").authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/api/security/user/changePassword").authenticated();
```

//         .anyRequest().authenticated();
http.headers().xssProtection()
.and().contentSecurityPolicy("default-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; form-action 'self';");
}

[set-cookie is send from request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVk3j.png)

[cookie received](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l91k7.png)

[there is no cookie in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98Cfm.png)

Comment: How do you verify that no cookie is being set in the browser? Do you see the `Set-Cookie` header being passed in the response?

Comment: yes header is being set. I posted additional images